# Unable to import third party framework into a cocoapod

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I have looked at the documentation on the Cocoapods site, several questions here and articles on various sites, but nothing thus far has resolved this for me.

The issue is that I had to create an iOS framework that needs to be placed into a private Cocoapod for use within my organization. I have focused on several variations of the vendored_frameworks option, but nothing has succeeded in importing the framework into my target project.

Below is a subset of my Podspec file:

```
s.name                  = "MyCocoaPod"
s.source_files          = 'MyCocoaPod/Classes/**/*'
s.vendored_frameworks   = 'Framework/MyFramework.framework'
```

This project was created via the `pod lib create` command. The framework in question is located in the Frameworks\iOS folder under Pods project in Xcode.

On the file system, the framework is located at `ProjectName/Example/Pods/MyFramework.framework`.

The framework is written in C++ and works properly when placed in a regular project.

The installed version of Cocoapods is 0.39.0.

Some things that I have tried:

- Using s.ios.vendored_frameworks
- Using preserve_paths
- Changed the path for vendored_frameworks to use the file system path
- Move the framework in to the MyCocoaPod/Classes folder
- Add the framework to s.source_files
- Using 'Framework/iOS/MyFramework.framework' for vendored_framework path

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally solved this odd case.

First, I deleted the project and had cocoapods generate a new one with the `pod lib create` command.

Next, I deleted the default folder under development pods and then copied the framework file into the project under the Development/PodName folder.

I then added `s.vendored_frameworks = 'MyFramework'` to the podspec file. Previously, I tested not including the Framework/ path under vendored_frameworks without success.

Upon importing to the target, it successfully appeared.

The only new thing I did was to use a new project, so I assume some setting in the previous one was incorrect.

Comment: When did you do pod install?

Comment: sorry i think i might have accidentally hit down vote, if you edit the answer i should be able to correct that.